# A listener for changing CurrentFrame in implay Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, listener, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to **create listener for implay in Matlab**. I would like to observe the change in CurrentFrame Value. It is possible?
This is what I have already tried:

```
app.myHandle = implay(app.filename1,app.framesPerSecond); 
myControls = myHandle.DataSource.Controls;
addlistener( myControls,'DataSource.Controls.CurrentFrame','PostGet',
@(myHandle,event)zmenaFramu(app,event));
```

But I got instant error:

```
Error using matlabshared.scopes.source.PlaybackControlsTimer/addlistener
The name 'DataSource.Controls.CurrentFrame' is not an accessible property for an instance of class
'matlabshared.scopes.source.PlaybackControlsTimer'.

Error in pokusnykralik/ButtonPushed (line 81)
                 addlistener( myControls,'DataSource.Controls.CurrentFrame','PostGet',@(myHandle,event)zmenaFramu(app,event));
 
Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.controller.ComponentController/executeUserCallback (line 386)
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.
```

I tried to name the property as CurrentFrame, myHandle ... but everything was with the same error. Any ideas? Thanks for any advice!